# Quick injection of data in C without 3rd party functions

Tags: c

This is my code I made. My objective at first is to make ABCDEF appear on the screen with the least amount of code possible given that ABC is from one memory space and DEF is from another memory space.

```
#include "stdio.h"

void catstring3(){
    char space[10];
    char toadd[5]={'D','E','F','\0'};
    char *string=space;
    char *addon=toadd;
    *string++='A';
    *string++='B';
    *string++='C';
    *string++='DEF' // how?
    *string++='\0';
    string=space;
    printf("Result: %s\n",string);
}

void catstring(){
    char space[10];
    char toadd[5]={'D','E','F','\0'};
    char *string=space;
    char *addon=toadd;
    *string++='A';
    *string++='B';
    *string++='C';
    while (*addon!='\0'){
    *string++=*addon++;
    }
    *string++='\0';
    string=space;
    printf("Result: %s\n",string);
}

void catstring2(){
    char space[10];
    char *string=space;
    *string++='A';
    *string++='B';
    *string++='C';
    *string++='D';
    *string++='E';
    *string++='F';
    *string++='\0';
    string=space;
    printf("Result: %s\n",string);
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    catstring();
    catstring2();
    catstring3();
    return 0;
}
```

Of all the functions, I feel the function catstring2 will produce the slowest results because I'm setting values of each string space and I added one line of code (one line per character of string). catstring is a bit cleaner but processing wise, its still the same. catstring3 will not execute at the `//how?` line because in conventional C I can't assign a string to a variable expecting a one-character value.

What I want to do is assign at least two bytes of data to a string pointer so that at least two bytes are modified at once in the string itself without the use of third party functions such as strcpy and memcpy and strcat.

Anyone know the easiest way to do this or am I stuck with setting only one character at a time?

Comment: Why not use `strcpy/strncpy`?

Comment: Why not `int main(void) { printf("Result: %s%s\n", "ABC", "DEF"); return 0; }`?  Since that's so obvious, and variants like `static const char abc[] = "ABC";` outside the function and `const char def[] = "DEF";` inside the function (to achieve 'different address spaces'), also work trivially, there has to a reason for doing all that excessive-looking work.  None of those looks sensible, but it isn't clear what rules mean you think that's necessary.  Using `strcpy()` and `strcat()` would be reasonable too.  Why isn't `printf()` a '3rd party' function? There's something we're not being told yet.

Comment: The 'how' line invokes implementation-defined behaviour; multi-character character constants have implementation defined values.  It copies at most one byte from the three letters, but isn't guaranteed to copy either `D` or `F`; it could copy a null byte if the implementation so chose, or pretty much anything else, too.

Comment: Jonathan I want to be able to modify the data later. If I can modify data via more direct access, then the overall execution speed will be faster. I could imagine the number of instructions required for the `strcpy()` command to modify two bytes of data.